# Why can we apply the Cauchy integral theorem to Laurent series' when $k\neq-1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, power-series

I'm working through a series of lectures in complex analysis, and I've encountered something that doesn't seem to agree with my understanding so far.

> Suppose $f$ is a complex-valued function with an isolated singularity at $z_0$. Suppose also that $f$ is analytic in $U=\lbrace r<|z-z_0|<R\rbrace\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ has a Laurent series expansion in the annulus $U$ given by
>
> $$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_o)^n$$

Now this part I understand well. The lecturer then proceeds to explain that,

> For $r<\rho<R$,
>
> $$\int_{|z-z_0|=\rho}f(z)~dz=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n\int_{|z-z_0|=\rho}(z-z_0)^n~dz$$

Now with this part I'm fine as well. I understand that the integral of a sum is equivalent to summing an integral in this case, as well as the fact that $a_n$ is just a constant, and can hence be removed from the integral. What I don't understand, however, is when the lecturer goes about evaluating the integral given that $k\neq-1$. It goes as follows

> As $k\neq-1$, then integrand becomes
>
> $$\frac{1}{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}$$
>
> yet, without consider the bounds given by any potential parameterisation of $|z-z_0|=\rho$, by Cauchy's integral theorem, we know that if $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain, $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, then
>
> $$\oint_\gamma f(z)~dz=0$$
>
> for every $\gamma\subseteq U$. Therefore, our original integral, when $k\neq-1$, evaluates to $0$.

This is where I got lost, because if $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$, then the domain is not simply connected, and Cauchy's integral theorem cannot be applied, or am I missing something? I've taken a loot at the question [when integrating a Laurent series $f(z)=\sum\limits_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}a_j(z-z_0)^j$, why do all terms for $j\neq-1$ dissappear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283770/when-integrating-a-laurent-series-fz-sum-limits-j-infty-inftya-jz-z), which asks why each of the terms of the laurent series disappear when $k\neq-1$. I can come to grips with why they disappear, given that the integral evaluates to $0$, but I don't understand why we can apply Cauchy's theorem to being with.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are right and your your lecturer is wrong: if $n<-1$, then Cauchy's integral theorem cannot be applied here (for the reason that you mentioned). And besides, if it could, why couldn't we apply it when $n=-1$ too?

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ne -1$, the function $(z-z_0)^n$ has the anti-derivative $F_n(z):=\frac{1}{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}$.

If $c(t)=z_0 +\rho e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2 \pi]$, then we have

$\int_{|z-z_0|=\rho}(z-z_0)^n ~dz= \int_{c}(z-z_0)^n ~dz= F_n(c(2 \pi))-F_n(c(0))=0$.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a prrof. The question is whether a certain proof is correct or not.